# importing flash library symbol into flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I am embedding a flash file in my flex file and then trying to add it to the stage. IU try addChild to a canvas element and to a container element, but it keeps giving me the error, the symbol "myBtn" is cannot be converted to a IUIcomponent.

I understand that I need to place everything inside some sort of component, but what is the proper way to do this in flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to rawChildren isn't the way to go here.  Containers ignore `rawChildren` when doing things such as layout, measurement, etc.

Instead, simply wrap it in a UIComponent:

```
[Embed(source="...")]
public var someSwf:Class;

public function addSwf():void
{
    var swf:Sprite = new someSwf();
    var wrapper:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    wrapper.addChild(swf);
    this.addChild(wrapper);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I just figured out after my last comment that i couldn't actually use anything in the rawChildren. This works better.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_3.html) for info on Embedding swf files and embedding swf symbols.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is use flex as a wrapper and then just use actionscript and flash the way i normally would inside of a container or canvas component. But it doesn't look like there is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to this post: http://craiggrummitt.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-add-children-in-flex.html

you use something called rawChildren.  so I would do myComponent.rawChildren.addChild('mymc');

Answer (score 0):

Here you can downlod a complement to conver a symbol into a flex component from Flash

[www.adobe.com/go/flex_ck_en](http://www.adobe.com/go/flex_ck_en)

You can add all your move into a symbol then convert to flex component

Select the symbol from the libary then go to:

Commands > Convert Symbol to Flex Component

then import the swc resultant in flex

finally add the elemento into flex:

```
    public var swfImported:NameOfTheSymbol=new NameOfTheSymbol();
    private function init():void{                      
stage.addChild(swfImported);
    }
```